# Scheduling a method call based on what the user has entered

Tags: java, timer, schedule

For example if the user has entered "3 5 19 23", the method should be called on 3:00, 5:00, 19:00 and 23:00 every day.
Can I handle this using Timer and TimerTask classes? If yes, How?

Comment: You can handle it better using `ScheduledExecutorService`, but wall-clock scheduling is not supported by either out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hmm... I guess you're right